# Rounding issue in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone please tell me,

How I can ROUND `7.3050` to `7.3000` in SQL Server 2008 R2?

I have tried :

```
  Select ROUND(7.3050,2)
```

Result : `7.31`

But I need result : `7.30`

Comment: Do you need it rounded to one decimal place or truncated to two?

Comment: Can you provide more examples? Is this actually truncation? Round down? Bankers rounding? Please try to explain what you want clearly. Giving one example only can often result in different interpretations, some sillier than others.

Comment: 7.305 does round to 7.31 - do you really want to round or to trim off all digits after the 2nd decimal place?  So should 7.307 be 7.31 or do you want it to still be 7.30?

Comment: You seem to have responded a few times to posted answers - are you able to post more examples or better define exactly what rounding you're actually looking for? As I predicted in my earlier comment, we're struggling when you only provide a single example of what you want.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `FLOOR` function in this way:

```
FLOOR(7.30502 * 100) / 100
```

If can change number of zeros to round it upto desired number of places.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply so quickly, but when I use its returning 7.305000

Answer (score 0):

What you get depends on how you start. The data type matters.

```
create table test (
  n decimal(10, 4) not null,
  r float not null
  );

insert into test values (7.3050, 7.3050);

select round(n, 2) as n_rounded,
       round(r, 2) as r_rounded
from test;

N_ROUNDED  R_ROUNDED
--
7.31       7.3
```

What you mean by *round* also matters.  When you talk about "rounding" 7.3050 to 7.30 (assuming a decimal data type), you might not really be talking about rounding.  (We can't tell for sure.) It *could* be you want to truncate to one decimal place--that you want to map all values between 7.300 to 7.309 to map to 7.3.

```
insert into test values (7.3000, 7.3000);
insert into test values (7.3090, 7.3090);

select round(n, 2, 1) as n_trunc,
       round(r, 2, 1) as r_trunc
from test;

N_TRUNC  R_TRUNC
--
7.3      7.3
7.3      7.29
7.3      7.3
```

Note the behavior of the float column.

Comment: Though this is because `SELECT CAST(CAST(7.3050 AS FLOAT) AS NUMERIC(38,37)) == 7.3049999999999997000000000000000000000`

Comment: The "type matters" only as so much as `7.3050` isn't exactly representable in a float, and it turns out that the nearest float value to it *happens* to have a lower value. For any other particular decimal value, the nearest float could have happened to be slightly higher than the decimal value, and so the rounding would happen in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am using data type "Decimal" which I cant change, can you please suggest any other way.

Comment: The expression `round(your_column, 2, 1)` gives the answer you want for 7.3050. None of us can suggest a better answer until you clarify what you expect from values like 7.3010 and 7.3090. What you call rounding in your original question isn't rounding unless you're talking about banker's rounding, which in my experience is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
Select ROUND(7.3050,1)
```

The result is 7.3000